# void setup()が繰り返し実行される

Tags: spresense

外部入力情報を検知しLTE通信にて通知する仕組みを制作してます。
void setup()にて初回に外部入力情報をLTE通信にて通知し、その後は外部入力の状態が変わった場合に
通知するようにしたいのですが、起動後数分経過（どれくらいの経過かは傾向を掴めてません）した後に
外部入力の状態が変わった場合に、void setup()の処理が実行されます。
void setup()はあくまでも電源ON時のみ実行としたいのですが、どうすればよいでしょうか？
＜開発環境＞
・Arduino IDE

＜ソースコード＞
暫く時間が経過した後にピンの状態を変化させると、void setup()が処理され、// 監視開始、初期通知送信  notify_process();にて初期通知がされます。void setup()の処理はあくまでも初回のみ実行とする方法があるのでしょうか？

```c
#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>
#include <SDHCI.h>
#include <LTE.h>

// APN data
char lte_apn[50];
char lte_user_name[50];
char lte_password[50];

// LINE Token
String notify_token;

// URL, path & port (for example: httpbin.org)
char server[] = "notify-api.line.me";
char postPath[] = "/api/notify";
int port = 443; // port 443 is the default for HTTPS

#define ROOTCA_FILE "ROOT/line-me.pem"
#define TOKEN_FILE "TOKEN/token.txt"
#define APNDATA_FILE "SYS/apndata.txt"

// initialize the library instance
LTE lteAccess;
LTETLSClient tlsClient;
HttpClient client = HttpClient(tlsClient, server, port);
SDClass theSD;

//ピン入力の前情報を保持
int prev_PIN_PWM[10];

//ピンヘッダ番号
const int input0 = 2;
const int input1 = 6;
const int input2 = 5;
const int input3 = 9;
const int input4 = 3;
const int input5 = 29;
const int input6 = 30;
const int input7 = 31;
const int input8 = 32;
const int input9 = 7;

void setup()
{
  // 初期化
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(LED0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(input0, INPUT);
  pinMode(input1, INPUT);
  pinMode(input2, INPUT);
  pinMode(input3, INPUT);
  pinMode(input4, INPUT);
  pinMode(input5, INPUT);
  pinMode(input6, INPUT);
  pinMode(input7, INPUT);
  pinMode(input8, INPUT);
  pinMode(input9, INPUT);

  prev_PIN_PWM[0] = digitalRead(input0);
  prev_PIN_PWM[1] = digitalRead(input1);
  prev_PIN_PWM[2] = digitalRead(input2);
  prev_PIN_PWM[3] = digitalRead(input3);
  prev_PIN_PWM[4] = digitalRead(input4);
  prev_PIN_PWM[5] = digitalRead(input5);
  prev_PIN_PWM[6] = digitalRead(input6);
  prev_PIN_PWM[7] = digitalRead(input7);
  prev_PIN_PWM[8] = digitalRead(input8);
  prev_PIN_PWM[9] = digitalRead(input9);

  while (!theSD.begin()) {
    ; 
  }

  // SDカードから証明書ファイルを読み込む
  File rootCertsFile = theSD.open(ROOTCA_FILE, FILE_READ);
  tlsClient.setCACert(rootCertsFile, rootCertsFile.available());
  rootCertsFile.close();

  // SDカードからapndata情報を読み込む
  getApndata();  
  // SDカードからTOKEN情報を読み込む
  notify_token = getToken();

  // 監視開始、初期通知送信
  notify_process();

}

String getToken(){

  // SDカードからTOKEN情報を読み込む
  File tokenDataFile = theSD.open(TOKEN_FILE);
  String str;
  // もしファイルが開けたら
  if (tokenDataFile) {
        //---1byteずつ読み込んだ文字を結合
        while (tokenDataFile.available()) {
            str += char(tokenDataFile.read());
        }
    } else{
        Serial.println("tokenDataFile error");
    }  
  //---ファイルを閉じる
  tokenDataFile.close();
  return(str);
}

void getApndata(){

  // SDカードからapndata情報を読み込む
  File apndataFile = theSD.open(APNDATA_FILE);
  String str;
  String cmds[3] = {"\0"}; // 分割された文字列を格納する配列 

  // もしファイルが開けたら
  if (apndataFile) {
        //---1byteずつ読み込んだ文字を結合
        while (apndataFile.available()) {
            str += char(apndataFile.read());
        }

        // 分割数 = 分割処理(文字列, 区切り文字, 配列) 
        int index = split(str, ',', cmds);
  } else{
      Serial.println("apndataFile error");
  }

  cmds[0].toCharArray(lte_apn, 50);
  cmds[1].toCharArray(lte_user_name, 50);
  cmds[2].toCharArray(lte_password, 50);

  //---ファイルを閉じる
  apndataFile.close();

}

int split(String data, char delimiter, String *dst){
    int index = 0;
    int arraySize = (sizeof(data)/sizeof((data)[0]));  
    int datalength = data.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < datalength; i++) {
        char tmp = data.charAt(i);
        if ( tmp == delimiter ) {
            index++;
            if ( index > (arraySize - 1)) return -1;
        }
        else dst[index] += tmp;
    }
    return (index + 1);
}

void send_line_process(String message)
{

  digitalWrite(LED0, HIGH);  
  send_line_notify(message);
  digitalWrite(LED0, LOW);      
  sleep(1);

}

void send_line_notify(String message) {

  // LTE接続開始
  while (true) {
    if (lteAccess.begin() == LTE_SEARCHING) {
      if (lteAccess.attach(lte_apn, lte_user_name, lte_password) == LTE_READY) {
        Serial.println("lte success");
        break;
      }
      Serial.println("lte error");
      lteAccess.shutdown();
      sleep(1);
    }
  }

  // 送信データ準備
  String contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded\nAuthorization: Bearer " + String(notify_token);
  String postData = "message=" + String(message);

  // HTTPS POST送信
  client.post(postPath, contentType, postData);

  // 応答コードを表示
  int statusCode = client.responseStatusCode();
  String response = client.responseBody();

  Serial.println("Status code:" + String(statusCode));
  Serial.println("Response:" + response);

  // LTE接続停止
  Serial.println("lte disconnecting");

  client.stop();
  lteAccess.shutdown();

}

int check_contact(int cur_PIN,int prev_PIN) {

  boolean notice_err = false;
  boolean notice_rec = false;
  String msg;

  //状態が変化した場合
  if (cur_PIN != prev_PIN) {
    // 接点がON（エラー）またはOFF（復帰）になったら通知
    if (cur_PIN == 0) {
      notice_err = true;
    } else if (cur_PIN == 1) {
      notice_rec = true;
    } 

    if (notice_err == true){
      msg = "ERROR NOTIFY";
      send_line_process(msg);
    } else if (notice_rec == true){
      msg = "RETURN NOTIFY";
      send_line_process(msg);
    }

    prev_PIN = cur_PIN;
  }
  return prev_PIN;
}

String check_contact_reg(int cur_PIN) {

  boolean notice_err = false;
  boolean notice_rec = false;
  String msg;

  if (cur_PIN == 0) {
    notice_err = true;
  } else if (cur_PIN == 1) {
    notice_rec = true;
  } 

  if (notice_err == true){
    msg += "ERROR";      
  } else if (notice_err == false) {
    msg += "OK";      
  }    
  return msg;
}

void notify_process()
{

  String msg;

  // curSW 0…ON 1…OFF
  int cur_PIN_PWM[10];
  cur_PIN_PWM[0] = digitalRead(input0);
  cur_PIN_PWM[1] = digitalRead(input1);
  cur_PIN_PWM[2] = digitalRead(input2);
  cur_PIN_PWM[3] = digitalRead(input3);
  cur_PIN_PWM[4] = digitalRead(input4);
  cur_PIN_PWM[5] = digitalRead(input5);
  cur_PIN_PWM[6] = digitalRead(input6);
  cur_PIN_PWM[7] = digitalRead(input7);
  cur_PIN_PWM[8] = digitalRead(input8);
  cur_PIN_PWM[9] = digitalRead(input9);

  msg = "INITIAL NOTIFY";    

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    msg += "\n";
    msg += check_contact_reg(cur_PIN_PWM[i]);
  }

  send_line_process(msg); 

}

void loop()
{

  // curSW 0…ON 1…OFF
  int cur_PIN_PWM[10];
  cur_PIN_PWM[0] = digitalRead(input0);
  cur_PIN_PWM[1] = digitalRead(input1);
  cur_PIN_PWM[2] = digitalRead(input2);
  cur_PIN_PWM[3] = digitalRead(input3);
  cur_PIN_PWM[4] = digitalRead(input4);
  cur_PIN_PWM[5] = digitalRead(input5);
  cur_PIN_PWM[6] = digitalRead(input6);
  cur_PIN_PWM[7] = digitalRead(input7);
  cur_PIN_PWM[8] = digitalRead(input8);
  cur_PIN_PWM[9] = digitalRead(input9);

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    prev_PIN_PWM[i] = check_contact(cur_PIN_PWM[i],prev_PIN_PWM[i]);
  }

  sleep(1);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setupが実行される、のではなくて、CPUがリセットされる、あるいは、プログラムが暴走して最初から実行される、のではないでしょうか。

信号の変化でそうなるという場合は、まずはそれによりリセット信号が影響されないか、あるいは電源電流の変化などで、電源電圧がドロップしないかなど、ハードウエア上での検討が必要となります。

電源はなにを使ってるのでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
モバイルバッテリーを使用しており、おっしゃる通り恐らく暫く時間が経過すると電圧ドロップし、その後入力状態が変わった際にリセット実行されているようです。
ボードの電源ランプが点灯していたので大丈夫だと思い込んでいたのですが、こういう動きになるのですね。
解決しまして大変助かりました、ありがとうございます。